# How to install py version selector on Windows if I forgot beforehand

Tags: python

So I am trying to use the "py" command on Windows to select between using Python 2 and 3, but it does not look like "py" got added to my PATH, and I am unsure whether or not it was even installed in the first place. What can I do to install py, or to check if it was already installed and then add it to my path? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To see if you have python installed and added to your path:

To add python to your path you need to go to ThisPc>properties>advanced system settings>environment variables>path.

If you believe you have it installed but don't have it on your path then make a basic python program and try running it in python IDLE. e.g print("Hello World") save it as a .py

Comment: I have python installed sure and can run it from the command line; I am talking about the "py" command to select between python 2 and 3....

Answer (score 0):

Just re-run the installer, use the modify/repair option, and select to install the py launcher.